# Following tensorflow pet detector tutorial, logs are empty in gcloud console

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to follow the tensorflow pet detector tutorial, but when I go to view the logs of my google cloud project, it says "No entries found matching current filter." I've tried pressing "show older logs" and "show newer logs" but still, no logs show up. Without the logs, I have no idea if my job is progressing or if it's just frozen (going to look under train, and it only shows the first checkpoint which leads me to suspect that the job is hanging somewhere). How can I enable these logs? The documentation said that logging is automatically enabled for training jobs, but that's not the case. Do I need to set any special permissions? The APIs are already enabled.

Thank you!

Comment: The "ML" tag concerns the programming language ML.

Comment: Can you clarify what tutorial you're using, and at what point you expect logs but aren't seeing them?